# wso2am Error while sending stream to wso2das

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

While trying to follow the instructions from the wso2am (1.10.0) manual, regarding [working with statistics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS) with the wso2das (3.0.1) server i have encountered a problem.

If i choose to let the wso2am server define the stream while making the first call of the api, the wso2das server refuses to post statistics to the WSO2_STATS_DB.

If on the other hand i choose to import the analytics.car file in wso2das   (as stated [here](http://www.rukspot.com/Publishing_APIM_Runtime_Statistics_to_DAS.html)  ) i get an exception (AsyncDataPublisher Stream definition already exist) because the org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request defined in the latest Analytics.car is different to the one being send from wso2am.

I pinpointed the problem in the definition of the Eventstream_request_1.0 in files
`org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request_1.0.0.json , 
throttledOutORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_REQUEST.xml`

where the definition of the throttledOut option is missing

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your DAS is in some kind of a corrupted state. Can you first delete the car application (/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps) and then log in to DAS and go to Manage  > Event > Streams and delete any existing streams.  Then try again to deploy the car app in the /repository/deployment/server/carbonapps location.

If everything goes well you would see two scripts in Manage > Batch Analytics   > Scripts  section. Try to execute each script and see if there is any error. If not then you can point the API manager to DAS

Comment: I followed the instructions and almost everything seems to be ok.
The only problem was the exception regarding the definition of the stream  

 `ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Stream definition already exist`


which was raised only once 

Other than that, i can see the stats!

Comment: forgot to ask. how did u deploy the car app. did u use the admin-dashboard as well. If you manually copy the car app to the deployment folder, then when u do the configuration from admin-dashboard, it also tries to deploy the car app. probably this could be the reason. You could skip the manually car app copying part if u use the admin-dashboard

Comment: The first time i deployed the app was using the admin dashboard, but that did not work well for me.  In my final (successful ) attempt, i copied it to the specified folder (after deleting an already present there)